# splitting string / bytes in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, split, byte, ctypes

I downloaded some code from Github for interfacing with a lab equipment:

```
readBuffer=ctypes.create_string_buffer(1024)
# some C functions modifying readBuffer using ctypes
deviceInfoList=readBuffer.value.split(',')
```

The last line shows an error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

`print(type(readBuffer.value))` shows `<class 'bytes'>`, and `print(readBuffer.value)` shows `b'0,NEWPORT 1936-R v1.2.2 04/06/12 SN22955\r;'`.

According to the SDK documentation file, `readBuffer is 'a character buffer with the following format: <DeviceID1>,<DeviceDescription1>;<DeviceID2>,<DeviceDescription2>;<DeviceIDX>,<DeviceDescriptionX>`. The last line of the code wants to extract the device ID (which is `0`).

`Split` should be a string method if I'm not mistaken, `readBuffer.value` looks like a `byte`, while the error complains that it is `string` not `byte`. What has gone wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `string` and `bytes` have a split method, that requires an argument of the same type. `','` is not a `bytes` object - hence the complaint. You want

```
deviceInfoList=readBuffer.value.split(b',')
```